# how to upload created xml file in django sqlite db

Tags: python, django, xml, database

I have a script that when user sends his data to my app I make an xml file and upload it for further use. I think there are two ways to implement it:

1. I can make a model that save xml file with its username and id to
   database
2. I can make a folder for each user and upload the file
       and save the url in database to refer to xml file.

   which one is efficient? and can I upload xml file to database? are there any other comfortable way to do it?

Comment: I prefer the 1st one.

Comment: Looks to me that this question boils down to ["*to blob, or not to blob*"](https://arxiv.org/ftp/cs/papers/0701/0701168.pdf).

Comment: thanks. but i have sqlite db. is it effecent to save?