# blob files on sqllite using django

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-models

I asked a queston in in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51945623/how-to-upload-created-xml-file-in-django-sqlite-db) about how to store xml files and they said for small files you better use blob.

how can I make models in django with blob in sqlite?

I search django model fiels and just there was filefield that i guess it does not save the files in database and it just save on storage how can i store blob files in django with sqlite?
can sqllite store blob files?

Comment: Sorry saving files in a database is bad advice. Don't mess with django's default of saving files on the file system. That's the optimal

Comment: do you mean that i should create my xml in view and save it to storage and send the link of file in database? and do you mean i dont use file field option?

Comment: FieldField is just that. The link is in the database, the file is on the file system.